# How to create RPC server for a C# application

Tags: c#, c, rpc

I have an existing C# application that I want to use it as a RPC server so a remote RPC client can call its C# functions.  I've searched and read the Microsoft RPC architecture in its Windows SDK.  It only uses C/C++ to create the RPC server application which requires generation of IDL, ACF files & the use of the MIDL compiler.

Microsoft RPC Server tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378869(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there a way I can use my existing C# application as a RPC server to work in such RPC architecture?  Perhaps RPC server C wrapper code calling my C# code? I'm just thinking out loud.

Thank you for your help, some sample code illustration would be very useful.

Comment: There is something very wrong with this question.  If you are doing this because you must talk to an existing RPC client then you should have asked "what do I do with the IDL or header file?"  If you don't have one that stop right there, it isn't going to work.  If you don't actually have a real RPC client then you should *never* use RPC, .NET has a much superior way to discover what client methods look like.  Reflection is impossible to beat.

Comment: Granted I do have to implement an IDL, the question I have is how to create the RPC server out of my C# application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kevin, this is possible, but I would also agree with Kirill, it is very difficult.

The primary issue is that the .idl language is C/C++ specific as is the generated code from the midl compiler.  I've done it before by compiling the .idl to the appropriate C/C++ client/server stubs and then translating the code into C# PInvoke.  This translation is Painful (with a capital "P").  The structures involved have circular references which makes it rather difficult, but not impossible, in C#.

Instead of fighting with loads of interface methods we chose the easier approach, a single entry-point.  To that end our IDL looks like the following:

```
[ uuid (546B0CE0-C70B-1067-B317-00DD010662DA),
  version(1.0),
  pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IRpcExec
{
    error_status_t Exec(
                    [in] handle_t Binding,
                    [in] long lDataSize,
                    [size_is(lDataSize)] byte arData[*],
                    [out] long *plReturnSize,
                    [out, size_is(,*plReturnSize)] byte **arReturn
                    );
}
```

The ACF then simply declares this to return errors:

```
interface IRpcExec
{
    [comm_status, fault_status] 
    Exec();
}
```

Effectively this allows us to receive a byte[], and return a byte[], thereby turning RPC into a simple transport layer rather than a full-blown protocol.  The full project and source are available from:

http://csharptest.net/browse/src/RpcLibrary/

Layered on top of this simple transport is a library to add support for a full-featured RPC mechanism via Google protocol buffers (using Skeet's [protobuf-csharp-port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)):

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-rpc/

Comment: Pardon my necroposting but may I suggest future readers look at: Microsoft's C++/CLI language (managed C++). I have been running into a lot of cross platform problems lately where I want to write a .NET library but have lots of calls to legacy C/C++ systems, or have to marshal C headers to external systems. C++/CLI makes it easy. RPC headers? Add it to my list of reasons to love C++/CLI.

Comment: If I had done that it would have required 4 binaries instead of just 1. PInvoke made this possible in a single .NET assembly that works on both x86/x64 platforms. Imho the C++/CLI integration is great for internal stuff, but tends to fall apart in open libraries. People have difficulty building and distributing native code whereas pure IL assemblies can go anywhere. Regardless how you get there, RPC FTW ;)

Comment: http://csharptest.net/browse/src/RpcLibrary/ is a broken link. New link: https://github.com/csharptest/CSharpTest.Net.RpcLibrary